# Magento Not Writing text after space

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am using custom form to save the state get request and save the selected field but i unable to save the state field after space.

**Ex:** Get "Jammu and Kashmir" and saving "Jammu"

Below is my code in Magento form

```
<select name="state" id="state" value="<?php echo $this->__('state') ?>" maxlength="50" class="input-text required-entry validate-alphanum-with-spaces"> 
    <option value="<?php echo $seller->getState();?>"><?php echo $seller->getState();?></option>   
    <?php                                   
    $regions = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('IN')->getRegions();          
    foreach($regions as $region)                            {                        
    echo "<option value= $region[name]>" . $region['name'] . "</option>";    
    }                 
    ?>                  
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put the option value into quotes.

```
foreach($regions as $region) {
    echo '<option value="$region[name]">' . $region['name'] . '</option>';    
}
```

Comment: foreach($regions as $region) {
    echo '<option value="$region[name]">' . $region['name'] . '</option>';    
}

Not working please tel me if any one have the method

Comment: @StalinAbburi What do you mean with not working? Csn you please post the exact error message?

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: If you like please mark my answer as solution. Thanks!